# What's the WMI limitation?

Tags: wmi

I have two computers, named A and B, they are in different domain and don't have trust connections between them, can I use WMI on A to operate B, or the opposite?
Yes per the answers from you and MSDN I know I can achieve it.
The fact is though I use administrator to do WMI operations, the process that remote started by WMI still does not have administrator privilege(In task manager the process user name still show as administrator).

Could you please tell me the reason?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:
WMI (windows management instrument) by itself can operate in conditions that you've mentioned. It's like sql style database, it works on computer.

If this is not the answer you expected, please clear up your question...

Comment: thank you, Lixas. I have clear up my question, could you please help to take a look at it?

Comment: @Daniel oh, i get it. Yes, you can connect to different domain machine in wmi providing appropriate wmi moniker(connection string). Read here more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx there are few examples in VB how to format moniker

Comment: thanks you, Lixas. Could you please help to check about the comment that I replied to nIKUNJ?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest limitations of WMI is, it requires Admin level credentials for WMI operations.
Now in your case, You can connect to machine B (in different domain) using local admin level user(which has administrator rights for his local machine B). You can also use domain level admin user which has administrator rights for domain of machine B.

Comment: Hi, the fact is though I use administrator to do WMI operations, the process that remote started by WMI still does not have administrator privilege(In task manager the process user name still show as administrator), can you know why?

Comment: You have to give administrator rights to the WMI class which you are accessing.(Control Panal-->Computer Management-->WMI Control)

Comment: when connecting to wmi you can provide different security levels and rights. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156574.aspx will explain you more. For example in my app i will be able to read system's all logs, except Security log, because i did not provide appropriate moniker. So, this may explain your problem

Comment: ConnectionOptions options1 = new ConnectionOptions();
options1.Username = "test"; //domain administrator
options1.Password = "password";
options1.EnablePrivileges = true;
options1.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
options1.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Call;
options1.Authority = "ntlmdomain:mydomain";
Console.WriteLine("begain to connect remote.");
ManagementScope scope1 = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + "myIp" + @"\root\CIMV2", options1);
scope1.Connect();

Comment: Hi, really appreciate to both of you. Above is the code that I used to remote started by WMI, could you please help to check what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is WMI does not pass your authentication level on to the remote host by default. To do so your account would need the right "Trusted for Delegation", which gives the very dangerous right to act as *any* account on the domain, and then you would need to change the authentication type in your WMI code to match this level. See this MS link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx